# Javascript checking whole document length in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with validation size of HTML after some interactions on the page complete in the loop.
After first iteration do{}while(), I try to validate size of plain text on the page (outerHTML), but it don't changed and loop stops activity.

If i try to execute command >document.documentElement.outerHTML.length out from loop: in browser console - i see that change size happend, and it don't work inside loop, but why?

Can somebody explain to me, please, how to correct loop behavior?

```js
var controlpagesize_int = 0;
do{
    controlpagesize_int = document.documentElement.outerHTML.length
    element_dom.click()
    sleep_fc(2000)
}while (controlpagesize_int != document.documentElement.outerHTML.length)
```

PS: sleep_fc() - is a timeout function

Thank You all:)

Comment: The outerHTML is a serialized domString of the element. Did you want maybe to use innerText to get the plain text and it's length in the element?

Comment: @lortschi, thanks for attention to my problem. Good question, but independently from implementation (innerHTML, outerHTML) loop is not working. Sincerely. I tried what You asked and it no give effect:)

Comment: while loop is going to now allow the page to update... `sleep_fc(2000)` is not possible to sleep.... so that is never going to work... You are literally running the loop a bunch a times in a row with no delay.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just doing an infinite loop. The loop is not going to allow the DOM to update. That sleep code is doing nothing

To match what you think you are doing would need to be done with a interval or timeout

```
var controlpagesize_int = document.documentElement.outerHTML.length;
function checkDOM () {
  if (controlpagesize_int === document.documentElement.outerHTML.length) {
    window.setTimeout(checkDOM, 1000);
  } else {
    console.log('Page Has Changed');
  }
}
checkDOM();
```

A better approach is probably to just use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  // looking at all the changes and find hello
  const newNode = mutationsList.find(mutation => [...mutation.addedNodes].some(node => node.textContent &&
 node.textContent === 'hello'));
  if (newNode) {
    console.log("updated with hello");
    // if you found the change you are looking for, remove the listener
    observer.disconnect();
  }
};


const targetNode = document.body;
const config = {
  // attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(targetNode, config);


window.setTimeout(function() {
  const temp = document.createElement("div");
  temp.innerHTML = "<p>hello</p>";
  document.body.appendChild(temp);
}, 5000);
```